# Web: Copy to clipboard (custom..)

Tags: javascript, flash, copy, clipboard

I know the best and easiest way to copy text to a clipboard that is both cross browser and simple is to use Flash, which is fine with me! I have come across this awesome plugin called [clippy](https://github.com/mojombo/clippy) but the problem is you have to embed the image or object onto the page.

I wanted to have a link that when clicked would do the copying. Any ideas? :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions) library, you can use any blocklevel element as your clipboard button.  This works because **zeroclipboard floats an invisible flash movie above the specified HTML blocklevel element**.

If you want to have a link clicked as to copy to clipboard, try something like the following:

```
<div id="d_clip_container" style="position:relative">
   <div id="d_clip_button"><a href="#">Copy to Clipboard</a></div>
</div>
```

And later:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
clip.glue( 'd_clip_button', 'd_clip_container' );
</script>
```

Note that **the `a` tag could be omitted here** because the clipboard button is floating over the containing div, not the link itself.